# I am getting high CLS on Mobile because the image won't stop loading late

Tags: css, optimization, responsive, pagespeed

this is [the page](https://yantranepal.com/mi-notebook-ultra-i7-11th-generation/) I am facing issue with  and here is the link to Google [Pagespeed report for Mobile](https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-yantranepal-com-mi-notebook-ultra-i7-11th-generation/42yy5m3a31?form_factor=mobile). I have tried stopping lazy load and also tried preloading the image but always there is a delay in loading the image. What can be the fix?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not so much that the image is downloaded late (setting [image dimensions](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/03/setting-height-width-images-important-again/) - which you have done - prevents CLS for this).

The issue is your JavaScript is doing something funky to load the image carousel where it collapses the carousel and then reinserted it. You can see in the PSI screenshots the carousel is not drawn initiallt and in fact more than that - the "Out of Stock badge" badge is partially covered. Then the carousel is inserted and everything shifts down.

It looks like you've solved that though as recent reruns do not show the issue?